# Is it possible to squelch build warnings for certain files/classes?

Tags: msbuild

I am currently building a project with `msbuild` that contains generated code. Is it possible to squelch build warnings from specific files (preferred) or classes?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of your code generation process you can use pragma statements in the code to suppress warnings.

At the top of the code you want to suppress warnings, add

```
#pragma warning disable
```

then at the end of the code add

```
#pragma warning restore
```

Note:  In most cases you will want to suppress only specific warnings. You do that with

```
#pragma warning disable warning-list
```

where warning-list is a comma-separated list of warning number without the prefixes.

---

Another option is to suppress specific warnings across the whole project. 
See [How to: Suppress Compiler Warnings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx)

Comment: Hmmm does that mean I have to add to all the generated code files? Is there a namespace version of this?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.   #pragma statements do not apply to namespace or class constructs.  They just change compiler behavior for the lines of code they cover.

Comment: Note the #pragma can be used to disable *specific* warnings which is almost always better than just disabling *all* of them.

Comment: @stijn  That isn't what the OP was asking for, but you make a good point.  I have edited the answer.